# How to concatenate <img src=" string" +document.getElementById(' ').value

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display images using `<img src=""` with the image path, but adding the actual image.png file as a variable from a text field.  I keep getting an error that the file does not exist... but it does.

I have tried searching the web, but nothing has fit this particular problem.

```
<label class="buslabel" for="Name">Window Pane Image:
   <strong><input id="WindowPaneImage" style="margin-left: 10px; border: 
      none; padding: 0;" type="text" class="busaddinput" 
      placeholder="Image.png" name="WindowPane" size="15" maxlength="15"        
      ></strong>
 </label>


<img src="C:/Users/jaydr_000/Desktop/Web Development/SFF/Vend-images/ + 
   document.getElementById('WindowPaneImage').value" 
   class="FrameRectangle">
```

Need to be able to get the input field [image name] and pass it to the

I keep getting an error that the file does not exist..., it does exist.

Comment: You can't inline JS like that in an image's src property. Bind a change event handler to your input and call a function to modify the image's src.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the work : As soon as you enter the name of the picture and click anywhere, the new image is served.

```
<body>
    <label class="buslabel" for="Name">Window Pane Image:
        <strong>
            <input 
                id="WindowPaneImage"
                style="margin-left: 10px; border: none; padding: 0;" 
                type="text" 
                class="busaddinput" 
                placeholder="Image.png" 
                name="WindowPane" 
                size="100" 
                maxlength="100"
                onchange="foo()"
            >
        </strong>
    </label>
    <img src= "" class="FrameRectangle" id="img">
    <script>  
        function foo(){  
            var name1 = document.getElementById("WindowPaneImage").value;  
            document.getElementById("img").src = name1; 
        }
    </script>  
</body>
```

Comment: OxVikas, I tried your code & here is what I get when I do an inspect element... the following error:    Bradken.png:1 GET file:///C:/Users/jaydr_000/Desktop/Web%20Development/SFF/Bradken.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Image (async)
foo @ script.js:280
onclick @ index.html:1059                       I can see that it did create the proper string for the file path and the "input" file name of Bradken.png is all correct.    Can you see any obvious issues?

Comment: OxVikas,   I just looked at the path again and realized that it is looking in the directory where the Index.html file is in & in the SFF/ directory there is another directory called:  Vendor-images.    So I copied the Bradken.png into the directory where Index file is and it worked!   Is their a solution to getting it to read a sub-directory where Index.html is?

Comment: I have one other question, can this function be called without a click event?  I need to be able to pull up a different Company and the image is the same as the last one looked at [onClick], so then you have to click the body to change images....  Need to be able to do this automatically...  hope this can be done.

Comment: An `onchange` (i think) event on the `input` could remove the need to click. But then it would change the src with every character and the image would probably show it doesn't exist until the full name were entered.

Comment: If you need the image src to only change when the image file name does exist, you could use javascript to make an... Xmlhttprequest (if memory serves) for the image file on each character change and only update the src when it returns a valid response. It's probably not the most efficient way, but it should work.

Comment: @Jay Reese, if you want to add the directory too, you can try doing `document.getElementById("img").src = "C:/some-folder/" + name1;` this should work. @Reed's `onchange` event soltion works fine too ! Add an if condition in the script to check if there is an image existing with the changed image name .

Comment: OxVikas  I was able to use the onclick version you originally provided above and it works great.  I put the onclick for a button to open a form & display the image with the current ID.  Also used document.getElementById("img").src = "C:/some-folder/" + name1; and it did the job.   ! appreciate it.